# Can't install steam due to missing curl

Tags: installation, dpkg, steam

Hi I am New to Ubuntu and when I try install steam, I get this-

```
varun@varun-XPS-M1330:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
[sudo] password for varun: 
(Reading database ... 179346 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace steam-launcher 1.0.0.39 (using steam_latest.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement steam-launcher ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
 steam-launcher depends on curl; however:
  Package curl is not installed.
 steam-launcher depends on jockey-common; however:
  Package jockey-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing steam-launcher (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam-launcher
```

Comment: Instead of installing through a `.deb` file use Ubuntu Software Center, Steam is available in the official repositories.

Comment: Thanks, Anyway I came to know I needed to install curl and jockey-common.

Answer (score 3):

Now try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Worked for me! Can you please explain this magic with "-f"?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try :

```
 
sudo apt-get install curl 
sudo apt-get install jockey-common
```

Thanks